# Simple PHP templating engine that allows to use PHP expressions insted of inventing its own language

Tags: php, templating, templating-engine

I'm looking for a simple PHP templating engine that allows to use PHP expressions in the substitutions. The "MVC ideal" that templates should contain just plain variable substitutions and nothing else often fails, which the common templating systems acknowledge and respond to by creating a syntax of "variable filters" (e.g. the things after a pipe in Smarty), essentially a new programming language.

When I want to do some small variable postprocessing in the template, I want to write `{strtolower(trim($a))}` and not `{$a|strip|lower}`, just because I don't want to remember two syntaxes (and often two names) for everything. I know it can be abused but I am perfectly capable of adhering to MVC myself, I don't need a language to force me to do so. This (using native language expressions) is a completely common thing e.g. in Python templating engines.

On the other hand, I'm not interested in the answer "PHP". That's too verbose (and ugly) for templating, even with the alternative syntax (`for:...endfor;`) and `<?=`. I want a nice and simple syntax for variable (expression) substitution, `for`, `if`, etc. It could in fact be a very thin syntactic-sugar layer over PHP.

Does anything resembling the above description exist?

Comment: Create a script that replaces `{` with `<?php print(` and `}` with `); ?>`. I mean, there will be a reason why template engines invent their own languages. If f.e. the tag inside the { } doesn't start with a $, how will you distinguish variable output from a for-loop? I really think short-open tags is what you want...

Comment: Yes, that's what I think I'll do in the end: a simple preprocessor, perhaps in sed or awk or whatever. As I mentinoned, such properties are absolutely normal in the Python and Ruby templating world, so it definitely can be done in an elegant way. The PHP people just seem to have a different way of thinking, for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to use php expressions within the templates, you can use the php shorthand syntax. If you want to take this route, I would suggest that you don't go a for a templating system that offers you some syntactic sugar as **you will loose out on IDE hints such as syntax highlighting and lint**.

For an instance if you want to echo a variable, you could do this:

```
<h1><?=$name?></h1>
<h2><?=strtolower($name)?></h2>
```

For conditionals:

```
<?php if(true): ?>
Some markup
<?php endif; ?>
```

A similar syntax can be used for loops as well.

Happy hacking!

Comment: please, do NOT use the shorthand notation (`<?=$var;?>`), for several reasons; 1) it is less readable, 2) not switched on in every configuration, which will break up your code if you move it ie. to another server, or use a snippet on another site and 3) are you really that lazy...?

Comment: @giorgio Thank you for your feeback. I understand your concern of the shorthand notation being disabled on some configurations. However, how does it affect readability? These notations will be used within templates and and helps to reduce verbosity. Lazy is subjective and will not delve into it :)

Comment: Thanks, but writing a vim syntax highlighter is a matter of minutes (I can just say where I want to highlight PHP syntax and import the existing PHP rules for that context... really neat) even if one doesn't exist already (for many templating systems it does). As for other stuff like code completion and suchlike... never used these in the last few years, won't miss. A clean syntax would be much more valuable for me. And last: it's (mostly) not about laziness, but readability.

Comment: @regnarg I use vim as my IDE, code completion is something that I don't rely on either, but linting has been very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to a simple PHP template engine i wrote: http://hardcoder.nazuka.net/projects/lint/